# How to create a "Make this Sticky" link or tab

Tags: 8, nodes

I need faster way to promote a node I'm looking at.

I usually go for:

- "Open node view page"  (IE: https://example.com/node/123)
- "Click Edit"  (IE: https://example.com/node/123/edit)
- Scroll down
- Click "PROMOTION OPTIONS"
- Tick the Sticky option
- Scroll (again)
- Save node

Is there a faster way than that? The idea is to have a "Make this sticky" tab or link.

Answer (score 0):

I just released [Toggle Sticky Toggler](https://www.drupal.org/project/toggle_sticky_toggler). Which adds a "Make Sticky / Unmake Sticky" tab next to the default "Edit" tab.

[image]